# Authentication for a blazor server controller

Tags: authentication, blazor

I have a Blazor server application where I have a controller where I access some methods.
My Blazor project uses Microsoft Azure AD to log in the user.
On my pages I have something like this to authenticate users.
`@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "App.Users")]` and that work just fine.

But in my controller file I have the same `[Authorize(Policy = "App.Users")]`, but this is not working. When I call my method I can see that the response i some kind of login.
I guess i tries to get me to login.

On the other hand if I enter the api call directly in my browser address bar it works fine.

I am using IHttpClientFactory to call my api controller method.

Can anyone please help me or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: If I use the tag [AllowAnonymous] it works, but this is not what I want.

Comment: On which server is the controller?  Same as the Blazor Server?  Are you adding  Authorization Headers to your API calls?

Comment: Right now I am still running it from Visual Studio. It is not on the ser yet.
I am not sure what you mean by Authorization Headers.

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer.
I just put my delete method in a class file with the [Authorize(Policy = "App.Users")] and it works now.